# Multiple records and determine if a combination if values exist and write this to a new column

Tags: db2, partitioning, group-by

I'm struggling with a problem.

An order can have multiple lines and accordingly a type (F=Footwear/N=Non-FTW,Mixed=Both)
I need to determine if the order consists of which type and create a new column with this information.

```
ORDR                         | TYPE
-----------------------------------------
#31900440220151005215630000  | F
#31900440220151005215630000  | N
#31900440220151005215630000  | N
#31900440220151005215680000  | N
#31900440220151005215680000  | N
#31900440220151005215680000  | N
#31900440220151005215680000  | N
#31900440220151005215680000  | N
#31900440220151005215710000  | F
#31900440220151005215720000  | F
#31900440220151005215740000  | F
```

What I want to have is ultimately:

```
ORDR                         | TYPE  | New column
------------------------------------------------
#31900440220151005215630000  | F    |   Mixed
#31900440220151005215630000  | N    |   Mixed
#31900440220151005215630000  | N    |   Mixed
#31900440220151005215680000  | N    |   Non-FTW
#31900440220151005215680000  | N    |   Non-FTW
#31900440220151005215680000  | N    |   Non-FTW
#31900440220151005215680000  | N    |   Non-FTW
#31900440220151005215680000  | N    |   Non-FTW
#31900440220151005215710000  | F    |   FTW
#31900440220151005215720000  | F    |   FTW
#31900440220151005215740000  | F    |   FTW
```

I thought of `partition over` but currently i'm stuck.

Comment: You may be better off going with a view. A table would be hard to maintain with this. Then your app would have to figure this out, or you would need a trigger or stored proc to determine the change in the new column based on inserts, updates, or deletes.

So I vote you either go with a view or use a trigger or stored proc if you really want this information in the table.

Comment: Why would you want to denormalize like this?  If you have an ORDER_LINE table like you're describing, don't you have a corresponding ORDER table, too?  This column really belongs in the ORDER table.  As @ChrisAldrich suggests, this column (if its really necessary) should be maintained by a trigger (or in the application code).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an Update to the existing table, one solution would be:

```
UPDATE t
SET t.New_Column = CASE WHEN types.mintype = 'F' and types.maxtype = 'F' THEN 'FTW'
                        WHEN types.mintype = 'N' and types.maxtype = 'N' THEN 'Non-FTW'
                        WHEN types.mintype = 'F' AND types.maxtype = 'N' THEN 'Mixed' END
FROM tbl t
INNER JOIN 
(SELECT ORDR, 
       MIN(TYPE) mintype,
       MAX(TYPE) maxtype
FROM tbl
GROUP BY ORDR) types
    ON t.ORDR = types.ORDR
```

Though, I would also, as Chris Aldrich said in the comments, suggest using a view. That view could be:

```
CREATE VIEW v_tbl
AS 
SELECT t.ORDR, 
       t.TYPE,
       CASE WHEN types.mintype = 'F' and types.maxtype = 'F' THEN 'FTW'
            WHEN types.mintype = 'N' and types.maxtype = 'N' THEN 'Non-FTW'
            WHEN types.mintype = 'F' AND types.maxtype = 'N' THEN 'Mixed' END New_Column
FROM tbl t
INNER JOIN 
(SELECT ORDR, 
       MIN(TYPE) mintype,
       MAX(TYPE) maxtype
FROM tbl
GROUP BY ORDR) types
    ON t.ORDR = types.ORDR
```

Comment: thanks, see my other post :) you saved my day and brains

Comment: Wonderful, Martijin. First- welcome to DBA Stack Exchange. The way to accept an answer is to click the check-mark near the top of the answer. It looks like you've submitted a new answer describing how this one worked for you- this one should be deleted. It will make the question most useful for those who look at it in the future.

Comment: Thomas,

THanks, it works like a charm. I used the piece of code not in a view but put it in a CTE together with the rest.

It is used eventualy for a report, hence the CTE functionality. But yes thanks My brains were locked and since i do not use this logic very much in daily usage

Many thanks :)